# How to show the query set result using cursor in the view

Tags: python, django

I have this function that run a query and pass the result to be showed in the view.

```
 def index(request):
        data = dict()    
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT user.email, item.id, count(item.author_id)
                          FROM item INNER JOIN user on item.user_id = user.id
                          GROUP BY item.author_id ''')
        data['item'] = cursor.fetchall();

        return render(request, 'ideax/panel.html', data)
```

Example of the queryset result:

```
[('teste@gmail.com', 1, 4), ('admin@gmail.com', 2, 5)]
```

How can I show the result of this query in my `panel.html`?

I tried this one, but it doesn't works:

```
{% for d in item %}

    {{d.email}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Use a model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Could you tell me a little bit more? I didn' get it.

Comment: What didn't you get? Models are a fundamental part of Django. You should go and do the tutorial.

Comment: I tried it, but I can't got the same result of the query. I had difficult to do joins and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is returning the tuple so we have to unpack like below

```
{% for email, item_id, count in item %}
    {{email}}
{% endfor %}
```

or we can also use indexes

```
{% for d in item %}
    {{ d.0 }}
{% endfor %}
```